# Chaining an existing filter inside a custom filter?

Tags: angularjs, chaining, angular-filters

I have a custom filter that uses the `number` filter and a custom `partspermillion` filter that adds "ppm" at the end. Currently I am chaining my filters, i.e. `input | number | partspermillion`. However I find this long to type, I want my custom filter to use the number filter everytime. Code as follows:

```
.filter('partspermillion', function() {
    return function (input) {
        return input + 'ppm';
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call your existing filter from new filter using $filter service.

```
   .filter('partspermillion', function($filter) {
        return function (input) {
            return $filter('number')(input) + 'ppm';
        }
    })
```